# Mac OS X Terminal: Search output of another command with grep

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal, grep

I am trying to get the output of an ls command and search that list for a regex expression... Effectively, it will search every file name in the folder for the regex expression.  I put together a simple example of what I thought was the right way to do this, but clearly was not:

$ ls ~/Desktop/testFolder | grep -rn "contents"

I know, I can make a script for this where I pipe the output from the 'ls' to a text file, and then grep that.. but I am asking how to do this WITHOUT a multistep process or script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command should work, although you do not need the -r option in the grep command. What happens when you try running your command that is not what you expected?

```
ls /path | grep string
```

The above works for me.

You could also try looking at the find command:

```
find ~/Desktop/testFolder -iname '*contents*'
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot guys! and those were some fast damn responses!

Answer (score 2):

Your only mistake is setting the `-r` option on `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want: `ls ~/Desktop/testFolder/*contents*`

Comment: yes, but I understand how a regular 'ls' works, no problems there